# Angular js select ng-options instead of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box where i generated options using ng-repeat, but i want that to be generated using ng-options

```
<select ng-change="onChangeShippingMethod(shippingMethodId)" ng-model="shippingMethodId" class="input-full-w normal_dropDown" name="gjh" id="select_shipping_method" >
    <option ng-repeat="shippingDetail in shipModeArr" value="{{shippingDetail.shipModeId}}" ng-selected="shippingDetail.shipModeId == selectedAddressPerItem[cartItems[0].cartItemId].shipModeId">
        {{shippingDetail.description}}&nbsp;Arrives {{shippingDetail.estArrivalDate | changeDateFormat | date:'mediumDate'}}{{shippingDetail.shipCharge | currency}}
    </option>
</select>
```

and i want a particular options should be selected based on some condition.

and using ng-repeat an empty options is coming with the other options

Please check in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_ngl/v49gto88/14/)

Comment: So, did you try anything? What went wrong?

Comment: @yoshi if i did with ng-repeat an empty option is coming with the other options

Comment: @yoshi and for options text i am appending many values how i can do this using ng-options

Comment: @sameer Did you check the fiddle? Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came up with. You should really provide a plunker with some data yourself next time.

The interesting part for ng options is the list comprehension like style in

```
ng-options="sD.shipModeId as sD.description for sD in shipModeArr"
```

**Edit:**

```
ng-options="sD.shipModeId as format(sD) for sD in shipModeArr"
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.format = function(sd){
    return sd.description
    + ' Arrives '
    + sd.estArrivalDate + ' '
    + $filter('currency')(sd.shipCharge);
};
```

You can define yourself a function to get your objects formatted nicely. I edited the plunker to show you where to put the pieces. If you expand the $scope.format function to return your formatting this should work.

If you don't want an empty selection you will have to select an initial value.

**Edit2:**

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v49gto88/19/).

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AC82JN9jxaXqmrFdmzyq?p=preview)

Comment: I want `{{shippingDetail.description}}&nbsp;Arrives {{shippingDetail.estArrivalDate | changeDateFormat | date:'mediumDate'}}{{shippingDetail.shipCharge | currency}}` in options text not only description

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you would have provided some data then somebody would have developed fiddle for it Now i just can give you syntax try this applying on your code.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="searchState" ng-options="st.state for st in stateList | filter:searchCountry | orderBy:'state'">
<option value="">Select State</option>
```

Here i have demo in jsfiddle example for the ng-options. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krimple/2TKry/) for particular conditions to satisfy please mention those in next question or use filters as i showed in above code. please list your problem in more detail format. including data , app.js code and some html. good luck.